# How to bypass or override a validated column in Sharepoint

Tags: 2010

I have validated a date columns `[Date]>=TODAY()`. I need to bypass this validation when I edit another column in the list post facto? Thanks

Comment: Thank you jpussacq. The Date column which is validated is one of many others of Choice, Look up and Single line of text. Everything goes fine when I create a new item. However, if I want to edit the item the following day, I cannot. What shall I do? Again thanks a lot for your help:-)

Comment: Are you putting a date greather than today when do the edition?

Comment: No! I try to enter data in a field from a Choice column which was left empty at the time when the item was created in the past. In Datasheet view, it shows an exclamation mark which when clicked, it prompts me to discard my changes. Thank you for following up.

Comment: You need allways to put a date greather than today with this validation

Comment: I am not editing the date field in the date column. I am only editing the previously created item by entering data in another field of another column of choice which was left empty on purpose. How can I bypass this validation as a SharePoint owner? Date validation is a must for this application.

Comment: You cannot bypass the validation, but you can build an OR condition based on another field

Comment: and how can I do that please? I tried many OR condition options. I want to edit exclude one [Monitor] column -who will have to edit the item post facto- form the validation of the [Date] column which is '=[Date]>=TODAY( ). Shall I use OR or IF condition and how? I do not have access to SharePoint Designer. I have to play it through a validation  trick.

Comment: There is no way to detect that you are modifying another field. You have to think of another approach to validation

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Add more data to your question explained what are you trying to do (bussiness logic)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **list validation** rather than **column validation**. This type of validation allows you to combine multiple columns conditions. Then you could validate the Date field only in some cases. Depending on the value of other fields.

[image]

Comment: Thank you jpussacq. The Date column which is validated is one of many others of Choice, Look up and Single line of text. Everything goes fine when I create a new item. However, if I want to edit anything in that item the following day, I cannot. What shall I do? Again thanks a lot for your help:-)